# How to compare two full year dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

The idea in my example is to allow user to select only the year in `to` input already selected in `from` input (have the same year in from and to date input).

The issue here is that it works fine when we use the date picker but, when we hit manually the date into 'to' input, it compare juste the first number of the year `***8/04/14`, I want to wait until the user finish the full date example `2018/04/14` then I alert OK. I the actual code, if I take the example : `from = 2018/04/14`, `to = 2018/05/29`, So it compare `2018/04/14` with `from = 8/05/29`, it alert ok in the **8** of `2018` and not in the complete year.

```js
$("#from").on("change", function() {
    year();
    var from = $("#from").val();
    if (from) {
      var maxYear = new Date(from).getFullYear();
      $("#to").attr("max", maxYear+"-12-31");
      $("#to").attr("min", maxYear+"-01-01");
    }
});

$("#to").on("change", function(){
    year();
});

function year() {
    var from = $("#from").val();
    var to = $("#to").val();
    if(from && to && new Date(from).getFullYear() != new Date(to).getFullYear()) {
        $("#to").val("");
        alert("OK");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="from">from</div>
<input id="from" type="date">
<div class="to">to</div>
<input id="to" type="date">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$("#to").on("blur", function(){
   year();
});
```

That should active the check only after the input loses focus.

Comment: If you really wan't to check it while typing, you could fire it onChange, and check if the entered characters make a valid date. If not you just return.

Comment: @K-dari thanks, it can be a solution, it works it but what bothers me to click out the input to fire the alert :/

Comment: @Daniel Tok I thought about it but it does not work, he considers that 0002/01/05 is a validate date `Date.parse(to)`

Comment: well, then maybe he should consider don't doing that :D

Answer (score 1):

`Change` event is triggered when input change, if you want catch user event, or key event you should try to declare all "change code" as stand alone functions and add another eventListener.

Maybe with `blur` or `key down` will work as you want but lot of event exist : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp